# api response from string to int

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have an api response that first i need to split and second i need to transform it to int, sin that is what the error tells me error says

```
failed prop type: invalid prop ´minimumValue' of type string suplied to Slider, expected number
```

this the apicall code where i split the value

```
  useEffect(() => { 
async function BCcontroller() {
   const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');
   const vCreationUser = 8;
   const vSolicitudeId = 80;
   const { data } = await ForceApi.post(`/ConsultBCController.php`, {vSolicitudeId, vCreationUser});
        const [termA, termB, termC] = values.split(',');
        setvA(termA);
        setvB(termB);
        setvC(termC);
}
BCcontroller();


}, []);
```

this is the declaration

```
     const [A, setvA] = useState(1);
  const [B, setvB] = useState(2);
  const [C, setvC] = useState(3);
```

this is the slider code

```
<View style={{ alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <Slider 
                            maximumValue={3000}
                            minimumValue={A}
                            step={1}
                            value= {sliderValue}
                            onValueChange={newsliderValue => setsliderValue(newsliderValue)}  
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.slideText}>$3000 MXN</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.slideText}>${sliderValue} MXN</Text>
                    </View>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a number when you save it

```
setvA(Number(termA));
```

or convert to number when you consume it

```
minimumValue={Number(A)}
```

I recommend the conversion as you save into state as it allows you to consistently rely on your state variable ***always*** being the same type. Also, front loading the work once per update is more performant than doing it each time it is accessed/consumed.